# Jar Exportation Not Showing Images

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jar, export

I am a  new programmer to Java. I have a made a small Directory Application that I would like to export, but for some reason, whenever I try to export it to a runnable jar file, the result doesn't contain any of the images I specified within my program. Basically, I ran it in eclipse, and it worked fine, but when I ran it as an runnable JAR, it has no images. I have 5 .java files that are all bundled with eachother. My Images are found at Images/Image.png [I already made The Images folder a source folder.]

I have tried **eveything**, but for some reason i can't get it to work, if you have any knowledge on the topic, please tell me. I  don't know if its because I'm a noob or something I'm doing wrong.

```
static ImageIcon logoicon = new ImageIcon("Images/Logo.png");
```

Comment: How exactly are you loading and showing the images then? It sounds like as if you're relying on local disk file system paths instead of on the classpath.

Comment: I added a source folder to my project and in that folder I put in my 3 images. [Folder's name is "Images"]. I referred to them by using ImigIcon methods.

Comment: Did you add the images to the eclipse project (not just the directory they are in)?

Comment: Well i told Eclipse that it was a source folder. Is that enough?

Comment: No, it's not enough. I agree that this looks to be the age old problem of treating resources as files in a Jar file. Just remember that **files don't exist in Jar files** and you should be good. Search this forum also as you'll see this has been asked and answered a million times.

Comment: I tried all of the answers, but I need to know how to implement some of the answers.

Comment: Show us the code you're using now - have you heard of an SSCCE? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Well now you have! :D  Go make one, come back, and then we'll be able to help a lot more effectively.

Comment: I posted an example of my code ^-^ What I'm using anyway :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method I use:

```
 public static ImageIcon createImageIcon(final String path) {
    InputStream is = ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
    int length;
    try {
        length = is.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        is.read(data); 
        is.close();
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(data);
        return ii;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogManager.logCriticalProblem("Image not found at {} - {}", new Object[]{path, e.getMessage()});
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you have problems with this method, try altering the path you're using:

```
 "Images/Logo.png"
 "/Images/Logo.png"
 "src/Images/Logo.png"
 "/src/Images/Logo.png"
```

Or other combinations depending on your package structure.  For example, if your images are actually in `net.blah.fizz.Images`, your path would be `"/net/blah/fizz/Images/image.png"`

Comment: Was this useful?  Did you get anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `getResourceAsStream()` method ? Checkout [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/getClassgetResourceAsStream.htm) page for more information

Comment: As I said, I am quite a noob, I don't really know how to implement that to an ImigIcon.